# Highcharts Pie Chart via AJAX/JSON: But Slice Errors and Json Format Not Correct?

Tags: php, ajax, json, highcharts

I'm a newbie php/js/mysql programmer.

I'm trying to create a pie chart in highcharts using jquery, where the data is discovered dynamically via ajax from echo json_encode in php (includes a select query from mysql).

Two problems:

1) The pie chart has these trailing "Slice: 0 %" flares everywhere. Don't know where these are coming from, what it means, nor how to fix it.

2) Json is new to me. The json data feed appears to be getting through (firebug sees it), but the format looks like this. I'm trying to boil it down to name and percent number only. Like this ['Pages', 45.0] but not sure how. Is this done in the json/php or should it be done in the sql query itself?

```
[{"contenttype":"BLOGPOST","count(*)":"2076"},{"contenttype":"COMMENT","count(*)":"2054"},{"contenttype":"MAIL","count(*)":"29448"},{"contenttype":"PAGE","count(*)":"33819"}]
```

Any help much appreciated

**The highcharts js file is here:**

```
//Define the chart variable globally,
var chart;

//Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout to request again

function requestData() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'hc1.php',
    success: function(point) {
        var series = chart.series[0],
            shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20

        // add the point
        chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

        // call it again after one second
        setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
    },
    cache: false
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){

//Create the test  chart
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
            renderTo: 'mycontainer2',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            events: {load: requestData}
    },
    title: {text: 'Content Types in Wiki'},

tooltip: {formatter: function() {return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';}
  },

plotOptions: {
     pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           //color: Highcharts.theme.textColor || '#000000',
           //connectorColor: Highcharts.theme.textColor || '#000000',
           formatter: function() {
              return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
           }
        }
     }
  },



        series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Content',
        data: []
    }]
});
```

**The php file is here:**

```
<?php
// Set the JSON header
header("Content-type: text/json");

// Connect to db 
include('dbconnect.php');

// Count version 1 of content types of interest 
$query = ("select contenttype, count(*)
    from CONTENT
    where version='1' and contenttype='page' or contenttype='comment' or contenttype='blogpost' or contenttype='mail' or contenttype='drafts'
    group by CONTENT.contenttype;");

// execute query
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());

// create a php array and echo it as json
//$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
//echo json_encode($row);


$results = array(); while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) { $results[] = $row; }
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Comment: I am a little confused by your code.  It is adding a new data point to the plot every second.  This would be an odd thing to do with a pie chart?  Do you mean to redraw the pie chart every second (again seems odd)?  Or do you just want to draw that chart once?

Comment: Here is example of column chart may help you. http://sgeek.org/create-chart-using-mysql-highcharts/

Answer (score 0):

First problem, how do you get your data into a format that highcharts is going to accept (namely arrays of arrays, [[name,percent],[nextname,percent],etc])?  I would handle this in your PHP:

```
<snip>

// execute query
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());

$total = 0;
$results = array(); 

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) { 
  $results[$row["contenttype"] = $row["count()"];
  $total +=  $row["count()"];
}

$forHigh = array();
foreach ($results as $k => $v) {
    $forHigh[]=array($k,($v/$total) * 100); // get percent and push onto array
}

echo json_encode($forHigh); // this should be an array of array
```

Now that our JSON returned structure is ready for HighCharts, we just need to call the plot creation once after our JSON call to create the plot.  I would do it in the success callback of the $.ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'hc1.php', 
    success: function(jsonData) {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        <snip>
                series: [{
                  type: 'pie',
                  name: 'Content',
                  data: jsonData
                }]
        <snip>
    },
    cache: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mark. One more question. When I test the php script, with a "php -f hc1.php", it returns an empty set [ ]. No json string is generated. Is there something missing? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I could have an error in there, I do not regularly write PHP code (and I couldn't really test what I wrote).  The $row["count()"] bothered me when I typed it (I was surprised that your original JSON would leave that as a key name).  I would modify your sql query to be "select contenttype, count(*) as num" and then replace the "count()" with num.  If that doesn't work you'll have to step through and debug.